# Mailx and Gmail nss config dir

Tags: linux, command-line, smtp, gmail, mailx

I am trying to send mail from a Linux command line using the mailx command. I can send from my local domain no problem but I want to set up mail to send from my Gmail account as well as receive mail sent to my Gmail account.

After configuring my mail.rc like so:

```
account gmail {
set smtp=smtps://smtp.gmail.com:587
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=USERNAME@gmail.com
set smtp-auth-password=PASSWORD
set ssl-verify=ignore
}
```

I would get the error:

```
Resolving host smtp.gmail.com . . . done.
Connecting to 74.125.25.109 . . . connected.
Missing "nss-config-dir" variable.
"/home/USERNAME/dead.letter" 11/354
. . . message not sent.
```

After looking up what the "nss-config-dir" was [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/man/man1/mail.html), I located the certN.db and keyN.db files and added that to my mail.rc like so:

```
account gmail {
set smtp=smtps://smtp.gmail.com:587
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=USERNAME@gmail.com
set smtp-auth-password=PASSWORD
set ssl-verify=ignore
set nss-config-dir=/home/USER/.mozilla/firefox/LOCATION.default
}
```

now when I try to send mail using this command:

```
echo "sent from gmail account" | mailx -v -A gmail -s "Command line mail" SomeEmail@domain.com
```

I get this:

```
Resolving host smtp.gmail.com . . . done.
Connecting to 74.125.25.108 . . . connected.
COMMENT-->then it waits there for about 5 mins then spits out this:
SSL/TLS handshake failed: Unknown error -5938.
"/home/USER/dead.letter" 11/354
. . . message not sent.
```

Does anyone know how to either:
    A) Set up mailx/mail.rc to access Gmail but ignore needing the nss-config-dir BS?
    B) Set up mailx/mail.rc so that the nss-config-dir actually works?
    C) Set up mailx/mail.rc to access Gmail in another way(POP maybe -don't know if that's an option, haven't looked into it?)

Any help would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you for this it gave me a way to find an even better solution.
Supposedly these `keyN.db` and `certN.db` are databases of trusted certificate authorities.

I did a simple

```
find / -name "cert*.db"
```

to find where on my system has the `keyN.db` and `certN.db` files
on my system (Fedora 20).
I found them under `/etc/pki/nssdb/`.

Answer (score 14):

Solved it!

There are 2 ways you can go about solving this.

1. Go over [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/498588/smtp-gmail-com-from-bash-gives-error-in-certificate-peers-certificate-issuer) and follow user `ndasusers` answer. It will both create the `keyN.db` and `certN.db` files you need but also another one GMail SSL certificate that will solve another potential problem.
2. Or you can just copy the `keyN.db` and `certN.db` into a folder (`/etc/ssl/cert maybe`) and direct `mail.rc` there like so:

   ```
   account gmail {
       set smtp=smtps://smtp.gmail.com:587
       set smtp-auth=login
       set smtp-auth-user=USERNAME@gmail.com
       set smtp-auth-password=PASSWORD
       set ssl-verify=ignore
       set nss-config-dir=/etc/ssl/cert
   }
   ```

Make sure you have permission to access those files if you are not `root` user, that buggered me up for a good while.

Comment: The directory of nss is `/etc/pki/nssdb/`. This can also be used to point to `nss-config-dir`.

Comment: +1 to @k_o_ . For CentOS users, you should use /etc/pki/nssdb as /etc/pki is the default location for anything cert related, and includes a nssdb dir.